# Linq to SQL though refreshing context object not updated when using SP with merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, unit-testing

I've built unit tests for SP heavy sql server (2008) database using Linq to SQL. In short I begin a transaction during test initialization and in clean up these are rolled back.

This has worked fine so far. I've been able to verify the changes in db-rows as long as I've remembered to refresh the objects used.

Yesterday I wrote my first unit test for SP using [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). I'm able to verify the insert, but though I refresh the object with the updated row, the refreshed object is not updated with the changes. Has anyone experienced similar problems? Is there a workaround for this.

I've verified that the update works when running the SP outside unit tests.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if problem is that merge does not update my row  because it is inserted in the same transaction..

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not know anything about MERGE. It is impossible that MERGE has an influence on L2S. It works like any other DML statement. Probably, MERGE did not write what you expect or you are looking at the wrong L2S object or the transaction has rolled back or this is a different connection, ... Search for simple mistakes like that.

Comment: You are right! When I changed the SP I added an inner join to the merge source, but I missed updating the test arrangement with the same. That is why the merge ignored my row. I would have needed an extra pair of eyes to see that sooner. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Found the flaw in my test code. See my comment above.